# SBCL optimization: function type declaration

Tags: optimization, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

If I have a function that accepts function argument, for optimization purposes I can declare it to be a `function`, let's say

```
(defun foo (f)
   (declare (type function f))
   ...)
```

However, I can be even more specific:

```
(defun foo (f)
   (declare (type (function (double-float) double-float) f))
   ...)
```

i.e. telling that `f` will accept one `double-float` argument and return one `double-float` value. SBCL, however, seem to be able to perform a better optimization on the former and for the latter it says that it doesn't know if `f` is `fdefinition` (try to compile with `(optimize (speed 3))` declaration to reproduce).

So, my questions are:

- Am I doing something wrong? Especially If SBCL would do exactly the same thing for just `function` and `(function ...)` I would be OK with it, but it actually does worse. Or should it be considered a bug in SBCL?
- Is function type declaration in general useless in CL in terms of optimization for some reason?

SysInfo: SBCL 1.3.18

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this on SBCL 1.3.21 / Linux. `(defun foo (f) (declare (type (function (fixnum) fixnum) f)) (funcall f 10))` doesn't give a warning and the disassembly is the same as with `(type function f)`. SBCL also checks that the argument given to `(funcall f ...)` is a fixnum and derives that `FOO` returns a fixnum.

Comment: @jkiiski Windows only has 1.3.18 build at the moment, will compile and check with 1.3.21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the SBCL Manual (4.2.3 Getting Existing Programs to Run):

> Some incorrect declarations can only be detected by run-time type
>   checking [...] because the SBCL compiler does much more
>   type inference than other Common Lisp compilers, ***so an incorrect
>   declaration can do more damage***.

It's possible, that's why your function does worse with the variable type declarations included.

Further:

> The most common problem is with variables whose constant initial value
>   doesn't match the type declaration. Incorrect constant initial values
>   will always be flagged by a compile-time type error, and they are
>   simple to fix once located. Consider this code fragment:
>
> ```
>  (prog (foo)
>    (declare (fixnum foo))
>    (setq foo ...)
>    ...)
> ```
>
> Here foo is given an initial value of nil, but is declared to be a fixnum. Even if it is never read, the initial value of a
>   variable must match the declared type. There are two ways to fix this
>   problem. Change the declaration
>
> ```
>  (prog (foo)
>    (declare (type (or fixnum null) foo))
>    (setq foo ...)
>    ...)
> ```
>
> or change the initial value
>
> ```
>  (prog ((foo 0))
>    (declare (fixnum foo))
>    (setq foo ...)
>    ...)
> ```

This is from the manual for the current version of SBCL (1.4), so it may or may not apply to your situation.